# MySQL increase ordering speed by dynamic formula

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

I have an MySQL table with multiple colums and an efficiency formula that is based on the different colums and varies for different queries. The table contains over 10 million entries and is static, so there won't be added new entries.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `col1` INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, # this is an ID from another table used as a filter
    `col2` INT(5) NOT NULL,          # about 20 fixed integer
    `col3` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `col4` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,    # fixed decimals -2:0.5:2
    `col5` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,    # fixed decimal 5:0.5:10
    `col6` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `col7` INT(2) NOT NULL,          # fixed integer 0:5:15
    `col8` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,    # unknown decimals
    `col9` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,    # unknown decimals
    `col10` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   # unknown decimals
    `col11` INT(3) NOT NULL,         # unknown integer
    `col12` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   # unknown decimals
    `col13` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   # unknown decimals
    `col14` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   # unknown decimals
    `col15` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   # unknown decimals
    INDEX `Index1` (`col1`, `col5`, `col4`, `col2`, `col7`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

And these are two common auto generated queries:

```
SELECT col6,col5,col2,col3,col13,col14,col7,col1,col11,
       col13*col14*col2/col6 AS efficiency
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `col1` IN (19,1,2,39,40,34,35)
      AND `col5` = '6'
      AND col2 >= '1000' AND col2 <= '5600'
      AND `col4` = '0'
      AND col7 >= 0 AND col7 <= 15
      AND col13 >= 3.00 AND col13 <= 4.50
      AND col14 >= 0.60
    ORDER BY efficiency ASC, col13 ASC
    LIMIT 0, 1;

SELECT col6,col5,col2,col3,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col7,col1,col8*col10*col2*col9/col6 AS efficiency
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `col1` IN (8,11,9,12,16,17,19,24,42,20,43,21,44,22,45,23,25,1,2,3,4,5,28,31,27,39,40,41,34,35)
      AND `col5` = '6' AND col2 >= '1000' AND col2 <= '5600'
      AND `col4` = '0'
      AND col7 >= 0 AND col7 <= 15
      AND col8 >= 0.50
      AND col9 >= 0.35
      AND col10 >= 0.40
      AND col11 <= 15
      AND col12 >= 0.30
    ORDER BY efficiency ASC, col6 DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
```

The second query has all values of col1 in it to force using the Index

The query without the ORDER BY clause is much faster than with it.

I have many of these tables, so overall the database needs about 65 GB of storage. Another index would increase the space needed, right?

The time to process the query without the order and limit clause is 0,390 sec. (+ 1,922 sec. network to get the resulting few hundred entries). With both clauses it takes 1,781 sec.

Because the efficiency formula is sometimes different and results in a floating point number, an additional index seems to be the wrong way.

Another problem is, that I have to sort the same results a second time. Currently, I just call the query again, which needs (as expected) double the time. Is there a way to sort the given results again?

The query has to process a few hundred entries after the where clause. I think that should be much faster than the 2 sec.

What is the bottleneck in this scenario?

Comment: you could create a new table using the **Memory engine** , you can look at the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html , and when you are done with the queries , you simply drop that table, to free up the memory

Comment: update you question and add  your related  indexes

Comment: so if you wont be adding any new entries, simply create a new column add index to id update the new column with the desired data. This should improve your performance.

Comment: @knetsi - `MEMORY` is not likely to be any faster than an InnoDB table that is small enough to stay cached in RAM.

Comment: Change `INT(2)` to `TINYINT UNSIGNED` where appropriate.  Similarly for `INT(3)` -- to `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT`.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Because the efficiency formula is sometimes different and results in a floating point number, an additional index seems to be the wrong way.

One option is to definitely use indexes.  Why is the efficiency formula different?  If you just have a handful of such formulas, I would recommend storing them in the same or a different table and putting an index on each column.  Yes, you can have indexes on floating point numbers.

You would keep the formulas up-to-date using a trigger (in other databases, you could simply use computed columns, but MySQL does not support those before v8).

> The query has to process about 800 entries after the where clause.

This is not consistent with a 30 minute querying time, unless your rows are really, really wide.  Scanning a table with millions of rows should take time, but tens of seconds, not tens of minutes.  If you can adjust the conditions to be strict equality conditions (no `or`, no `in`), then an index can be used to find the 800 entries quite quickly.

As written now, an index would not be particularly helpful, unless `col2` is highly selective.

Comment: I will try to add a column with the results of the efficiency formula and put an index on this (+ the old ones?).

Why is an index not helpful unless col2 is highly selectiv?

Comment: @Marius . . . Most of the comparisons are inequalities.  Indexes work best on equality conditions.

Answer (score 0):

- Since the table is `static`, shrink each data type to the minimum.  This will cut back on I/O if that is part of the issue.
- Review the likely queries.  Discover which columns are tested with `=` (as are col2 and col4 in your example).
- Build a variety of 2-column indexes based on the `=` columns.
- Lengthen some of those indexes by *one* more column that is used in `IN` or a "range".
- Don't make more than about a dozen indexes.
- If you are usually computing `col1*col2/col3 AS efficiency`, then, good grief, make it a column.

Tell us what kind of numbers you are using (cost, meters, persons, dates/datetimes, etc); it could help in further advising.

**Specifics** based on queries presented:

Both queries would benefit from

```
INDEX(col4, col5, one-other-col)  -- where 4 and 5 are in either order
```

This puts all the `=` tests first in the index.  The third column should be whatever one is likely to be the most selective.  (Granted, this could be a guessing game.)

`IN` is worse than `=`, but not as bad as a range such as `<` (or a pair such as seen with `col7).  So it is hard to say whether`col1` is useful in the index.

After one "range" column is used, the Optimizer will ignore any further columns in the index.  So, in the original index, it can't get to `col7` because `col2` is a range.

Comment: What do you mean with "Build a variety of 2-column indexes based on the  
   = columns"? I only have one index at the moment and the database is 65 GB. Wouldn't many indexes increase the size rapidly?

Comment: @brnk - I added some specifics.